# left outer join returning redundant rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem getting the right records with correct amount of stocks.

Query for calculating "Stock In"

```
select r.id as 'reagent_id',r.name as 'name',s.liquid_quantity as 'liquid_quantity',sum(s.quantity) as 'stock_in_quantity'
  from stockin_detail s  
  left join reagent r on r.id = s.reagent_id 
  group by r.id,s.liquid_quantity
```

Query for calculating "Stock Out"

```
select r.id as 'reagent_id',r.name as 'name',s.liquid_quantity as 'liquid_quantity',sum(s.quantity) as 'stock_in_quantity'
  from stockout_detail s  
  left join reagent r on r.id = s.reagent_id 
  group by r.id,s.liquid_quantity
```

Current Output

```
STOCK IN                        
    REAGENT_ID | REAGENT_NAME | LIQUID_QUANTITY | STOCK_IN_QUANTITY
        2      |reagent2      | 30              | 3   
        2      |reagent2      | 100             | 3  
        2      |reagent3      | 30              | 2   
        2      |reagent3      | 100             | 5
STOCK OUT
    REAGENT_ID | REAGENT_NAME | LIQUID_QUANTITY | STOCK OUT QUANTITY
        2      |reagent2      | 30              | 1   
        2      |reagent2      | 100             | 2  
        2      |reagent3      | 30              | 1   
        2      |reagent3      | 100             | 1
```

Expected Output

```
REAGENT_ID | REAGENT_NAME | LIQUID_QUANTITY | CURRENT STOCKS
    2      |reagent2      | 30              | 2   
    2      |reagent2      | 100             | 1  
    2      |reagent3      | 30              | 1   
    2      |reagent3      | 100             | 4
```

I tried this query but it returns multiple redundant records with some incorrect values.

```
select i.reagent_id,i.name,i.stock_in_quantity-ifnull(o.stock_out_quantity,0) as 'SYSTEM_STOCK',i.liquid_quantity as 'LIQUID_QUANTITY', ' ' as 'PHYSICAL_COUNT'
from
 (
  select r.id as 'reagent_id',r.name as 'name',s.liquid_quantity as 'liquid_quantity',sum(s.quantity) as 'stock_in_quantity'
  from stockin_detail s  
  left join reagent r on r.id = s.reagent_id 
  group by r.id,s.liquid_quantity
 ) i
 left outer join
 (
  select r.id as 'reagent_id',r.name as 'name',s.liquid_quantity as 'liquid_quantity',sum(s.quantity) as 'stock_out_quantity'
  from stockout_detail s  
  left join reagent r on r.id = s.reagent_id 
  group by r.id,s.liquid_quantity
 ) o on i.name = o.name
```

Output of this query

```
REAGENT_ID | REAGENT_NAME | LIQUID_QUANTITY | CURRENT STOCKS
    2      |reagent2      | 30              | 2*  
    2      |reagent2      | 30              | 1  
    2      |reagent2      | 100             | 2   
    2      |reagent2      | 100             | 1*
    3      |reagent3      | 30              | 1*
    3      |reagent3      | 30              | 1*
    3      |reagent3      | 100             | 4*
    3      |reagent3      | 100             | 4*
```

Asterisked values are the correct records. however reagent3 correct records are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Joining two tables like below:

```
SELECT SI.REAGENT_ID, SI.REAGENT_NAME, SI.LIQUID_QUANTITY, SI.STOCK_IN_QUANTITY - SO.STOCK_OUT_QUANTITY
FROM STOCK_IN SI INNER JOIN STOCK_OUT SO
ON SI.REAGENT_ID = SO.REAGENT_ID
AND SI.REAGENT_NAME = SO.REAGENT_ID
AND SI.LIQUID_QUANTITY = SO.LIQUID_QUANTITY
```

Comment: this logic worked. Thank you very much sir! SOLVED. However I replaced INNER with LEFT join  so stock in quantity without stock out quantity will be shown.